# unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, templates, g++, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a templated class that holds a reference to an object of it's template parameter type, and a pointer to a void returning no arg member function of that class.  However I'm getting an error about `'<unresolved function type>'` when I compile.

```
template<class T>
class memberAction
{
public:
    memberAction(void (T::*func)() , T& object);
private:
    void (T::*m_func)();
    T& m_object;
};

template<class T>
memberAction<T>::memberAction(void (T::*func)() , T& object)
{
    m_func = func;
    m_object = object;
}

class File
{
public:
    File();
    void TELUNUS_Open();

    //memberAction<File>& getOpenAction();

private:
    memberAction<File> m_OpenAction;
};

File::File():
        m_OpenAction(TELUNUS_Open,*this)//Line with error on it
{

}

void File::Open()
{ 
    //
}
```

compiling with g++ 4.7.2 I get the following error message:

```
StackOverloadErrorExample.cpp|31|error: no matching function for call to 'memberAction<File>::memberAction(<unresolved overloaded function type>, File&)'|
```

It seems other people with a similar compiler error are confusing pointers to global functions with pointers to member functions, but I specifically declare the constructor as taking a pointer to a member function of it's template parameter, and pass it a member function of the correct type.

So how do I resolve this compiler error?

Comment: I did not try it, but just by looking at it... shouldn't there be something like File::TELUNUS_Open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to pass `&File::TELUNUS_Open`—or `&File::Open`, whichever name you’ve actually called it—to get the member function pointer. `Open` has the *function* type `void (File::)()` whereas `&File::Open` has the type you really want, the *function pointer* type `void (File::*)()`. Beyond that, you’re going to have issues with the `m_object` reference member. The assignment operator will try to assign to an uninitialised reference:

```
template<class T>
memberAction<T>::memberAction(void (T::*func)() , T& object)
{
    m_func = func;
    m_object = object;
}
```

You should use a constructor initializer list instead:

```
template<class T>
memberAction<T>::memberAction(void (T::*func)() , T& object)
  : m_func(func),
    m_object(object) {}
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like you're right, thanks.  I'd thought I saw examples where function names were passed to functions that took function pointers as arguments somewhere.

Comment: @TELunus: You probably did; that *does* work for non–instance-member functions.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles, I believe:

```
template< class T >
class memberAction
{
 public:
  memberAction( void (T::*)(), T& );
 private:
  void (T::*m_func)();
  T& m_object;
};

template< class T >
memberAction< T >::memberAction( void (T::*func)(), T& object )
    : m_func( func ), m_object( object )
{    
}

class File
{
 public:
  File();
  void TELUNUS_Open()
  {
   return;
  }

  //memberAction<File>& getOpenAction();

 private:
  memberAction< File > m_OpenAction;
};

File::File()
    : m_OpenAction( &File::TELUNUS_Open, *this ) //Line with error on it
{
}
```