# Unresolved overloaded function type when function belong to a Class

Tags: c++, arduino, ticker

Im using the class [Ticker](http://links2004.github.io/Arduino/dd/de3/class_ticker.html) in my code as follows inside my class called HookNinja:

```
void HookNinja::pulser(float period, float onTime) {
  _ticker1.attach(period, HookNinja::pulseUp, onTime);
}

void HookNinja::pulseUp(float onTime) {
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  _ticker2.attach(onTime, HookNinja::pulseDown);
}

void HookNinja::pulseDown() {
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  _ticker2.detach();
}
```

According to Ticker documentation, the second parameter is a function, but a regular one, mine is inside a Class, and every time I try to compile I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Ticker::attach
(float&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, float&)'
```

This happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841338/c-unresolved-overloaded-function-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845230/unresolved-overloaded-function-type), but from those answer I cannot understand what should I do in my code to fix it.

Note: : _ticker1 and 2 are defined in my headers file.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that can be a problem of definition order: you first use `pulseUp()` and then you define it; you first use `pulseDown()` and then you define it.

My suggestion: try to invert the order: define `pulseDown()` first, `pulseUp()` next and, last, `pulser()`

```
void HookNinja::pulseDown() {
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  _ticker2.detach();
}

void HookNinja::pulseUp(float onTime) {
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  _ticker2.attach(onTime, HookNinja::pulseDown);
}

void HookNinja::pulser(float period, float onTime) {
  _ticker1.attach(period, HookNinja::pulseUp, onTime);
}
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English